# What type of lattice should I use for a privacy screen?

Tags: wood, screens

I'm building a privacy screen for a terrace. I'm using 3/4 mahogany for the frame. I've made grooves (dado cuts?) in which I am going  to place the lattice. The depth of the grooves is about a half an inch. The question-- what lattice to use? It was suggested that I use cedar lattice. Does that sound like a good choice? Also, are there standard openings for this lattice? I recall seeing openings of around 2.5" x 2.5". Is that the standard?

I'm making several panels. Each are 16" thick. I would like the lattice to be sturdy. I'm going to use some screws to screw the lattice into the frame.

So my basic question I guess-- **Is what type of lattice would you recommend?** I've also seen spruce-- not sure how this stacks up against cedar.

Comment: It's really entirely an aesthetic decision on your part. Whatever you feel looks best is what I'd go with.

Comment: Sounds like you're already quite far along, but to throw out an alternative: a friend of mine built a [louvered top privacy screen](http://www.flexfence.com/doItYourselfProjects/project12.shtml) on his deck, and I'm a huge fan. It's very functional since you  can open/close it to control/block the breeze, sun and amount of privacy, and IMHO it looks much nicer than the typical diamond-pattern privacy lattice most people use.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend you build it yourself.  None of the building supply versions that I've seen can stand up too much more than 3 years of weathering.  They use cheap fasteners that rust and stain the second year.

Self construction will allow custom size openings.  Weaving is another possibility.

Teak, ipe, redwood and cedar, in that order, would be my top choices for natural or stained.

Stainless fasteners are a must.

[Lattice construction atricle](http://www.hammerzone.com/archives/landscape/screen/lattice/custom1.htm)  [image]

[Google image search for lattice](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&safe=off&site=imghp&tbm=isch&source=hp&biw=1336&bih=833&q=lattice%20screen%20designs&oq=lattice%20screen%20&gs_l=img.1.1.0i24l5.2642.6432.0.9385.15.13.0.2.2.0.124.1009.12j1.13.0...0.0...1ac.1.7.img.3UOuOw1EwGc)[image]